# Asymptotic integration of $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}+a}J_{-\frac{1}{2}+a}(x\alpha)}{e^x-1}{\rm d}x$ when $\alpha \gg 1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions

What is the asymptotic integration of

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}+a}J_{-\frac{1}{2}+a}(x\alpha)}{e^x-1}{\rm d}x$$

when $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$. How to compute that using standard identities? Please give a general expression and then consider a special case where $a=\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: Mathematica didn't provide any result?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1972-26-118/S0025-5718-1972-0308695-9/S0025-5718-1972-0308695-9.pdf or https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82476688.pdf

Comment: Consider a new parameter $\frac{D}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}+a$ to write down the final answer.

Comment: @FaberBosch I added information on the error term.

Comment: @Gary Thank you very much! Could you please provide a link for the first identity involving Bernoulli's numbers? Also for the representation of the regularised hypergeometric function as the series summation?

Comment: Bernoulli: http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2.i (multiply both sides by $t^{a-3/2}$) Hypergeometric: combine http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E6 and the fact that $F (a,b;c;z)= \Gamma(c)\mathbf{F}(a,b;c;z)$.

Comment: @Gary Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We assume that $a>\frac{1}{2}$ is fixed. Note that
$$
\frac{{x^{a - 1/2} }}{{\mathrm{e}^x  - 1}} \sim \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_n }}{{n!}}x^{n + a - 3/2} } 
$$
as $x\to 0^+$, where $B_n$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers. Then, by Theorem $2$ in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/0507061), we find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{a - 1/2} }}{{\mathrm{e}^x  - 1}}J_{a - 1/2} (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x}  & \sim \frac{1}{{2}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_n }}{{n!}}\frac{\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{n}{2} + a - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}{\Gamma\! \left( {1-\frac{n}{2}} \right)}\!\left( {\frac{2}{\alpha }} \right)^{n + a - 1/2} } 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma \!\left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\!\left( {\frac{2}{\alpha }} \right)^{a - 1/2}  - \frac{{\Gamma (a)}}{{4\sqrt \pi  }}\left( {\frac{2}{\alpha }} \right)^{a + 1/2}  
\end{align*}
as $\alpha \to +\infty$. Note that the Bernoulli numbers of odd index $n\geq 3$ or the reciprocal gamma function eliminate all terms in the asymptotic expansion except the first two. The absolute error of this two-term approximation decays to zero faster in $\alpha$ than any negative power of $\alpha$. Thus, this asymptotics is rather accurate for large $\alpha$.

In the special case $a=\frac{5}{2}$, the aproximation is
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 }}{{\mathrm{e}^x  - 1}}J_2 (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x}  \sim \frac{2}{{\alpha ^2 }} - \frac{3}{{2\alpha ^3 }}.
$$
The right-hand side apporaches $0$ from above for large positive values of $\alpha$.

A different type of expansion may be obtained as follows. We can expand the denominator of the integrand and integrate term-by-term using [$(10.22.49)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E49), to deduce
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{a - 1/2} }}{{\mathrm{e}^x  - 1}}J_{a - 1/2} (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {x^{a - 1/2} \left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\mathrm{e}^{ - nx} } } \right)J_{a - 1/2} (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x} 
\\ &
 = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^{ + \infty } {x^{a - 1/2} \mathrm{e}^{ - nx} J_{a - 1/2} (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x} } 
\\ &
 = \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)^{a - 1/2} \Gamma (2a)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^{2a} }}{\bf F}\!\left( {a,a + \frac{1}{2};a + \frac{1}{2}; - \left( {\frac{\alpha }{n}} \right)^2 } \right)} 
\\ & = \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)^{a - 1/2} \frac{{\Gamma (2a)}}{{\Gamma \!\left( {a + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(n^2  + \alpha ^2 )^a }}} 
\\ &
 = (2\alpha )^{a - 1/2} \frac{{\Gamma (a)}}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(n^2  + \alpha ^2 )^a }}} 
\end{align*}
for $a>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha>0$. Here $\mathbf F$ stands for the regularised hypergeometric function. The last series is a generalised Mathieu series. Thus applying Theorem $1$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07751v1), we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{a - 1/2} }}{{\mathrm{e}^x  - 1}}J_{a - 1/2} (\alpha x)\,\mathrm{d}x}  = & \;\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\! \left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\!\left( {\frac{2}{\alpha }} \right)^{a - 1/2}  - \frac{{\Gamma (a)}}{{4\sqrt \pi  }}\left( {\frac{2}{\alpha }} \right)^{a + 1/2}  \\ & +(2\pi )^{a - 1/2} \frac{{\mathrm{e}^{ - 2\pi \alpha } }}{{\sqrt \alpha  }}\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{\alpha }} \right)} \right)
\end{align*}
as $\alpha \to +\infty$, with $a>\frac{1}{2}$ being fixed. This shows the exponential accuracy of our original two-term asymptotics.

Comment: $${{J}_{v}}\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{-i\infty }^{i\infty }{\frac{\Gamma \left( -s \right){{\left( \tfrac{1}{2}x \right)}^{v+2s}}}{\Gamma \left( v+s+1 \right)}ds}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\operatorname{Re}v>0,x>0$$
Then 
$${{f}_{v}}\left( \alpha  \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{x}^{v}}{{J}_{v}}\left( \alpha x \right)}{{{e}^{x}}-1}dx}=\frac{{{2}^{v}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{-i\infty }^{i\infty }{\Gamma \left( -s \right)\zeta \left( 2v+2s+1 \right)\Gamma \left( v+s+\tfrac{1}{2} \right){{\alpha }^{2s+v}}ds}$$
Two residues to the left yield the ~ expansion(?)

Comment: comment continued....I don't have access to the first paper you listed so i rolled my own version (not sure if this is what is done in that paper or not).

Comment: @mathstackuser12 Thanks for your comment. The first paper uses a different approach to Hankel transforms of quite general functions. What you did is related to the second paper. You after the two residue you need to study the remainder term. It must be the exponentially small one at the end of my answer. Minor point: the standard notation for the order of a Bessel function is $\nu$ (greek nu) and not $v$.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, especially regarding the second paper (which admittedly i didn't read).  Indeed i think the remainder has to be the exponentially small term in your answer - for my own interest, I'll work towards deriving it.

Comment: @mathstackuser12 The derivation of the complete exponentially small expansion for the error is given in the paper by Paris (the arXiv paper). He uses Mellin-Barnes integrals too.

Comment: @Gary I noticed that when $\alpha> 1$ even slightly then the integration is incredibly accurate. I'm also interested in seeing if the integral can be asymptotically expanded around the point $\alpha=1$, that is as $\alpha\rightarrow 1$ from the region $\alpha<1$. Should I edit this in the original question or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: That is because the absolute error is $\sim e^{-2\pi \alpha}$ (see the last displayed formula), which is already small for $\alpha \approx 1$. For $\alpha \to 1$, you will have a convergent power series, because the function is analytic at $\alpha=1$. You may ask a separate question if you like.

Comment: @Gary I've asked it here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281835/asymptotic-power-series-expansion-of-int-0-infty-fracx-fracd2j-frac). Please see if you have the time to answer then the answers will be homogeneous.

Comment: @Gary I understand for all odd $n\geq3$ the Bernoulli numbers all go to zero, however I don't understand what happens to the reciprocal gammas that they eliminate rest of the asymptotic terms save for the first two. Could you please add a line or two of explanation?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-k)}=0$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$.