# Asymptotic power series expansion of $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\nu J_\nu(x\alpha)}{e^x-1}{\rm d}x$ around $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha<1$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics, special-functions

What is the power series expansion $f(\alpha)$ as $\alpha\to 1$ and also in the limit $\alpha\ll 1$, where

$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\nu J_\nu(x\alpha)}{e^x-1}{\rm d}x$$

At $\alpha=1$ the integrand is analytic so we should have a convergent power series. The power series expansion for the case $\alpha\gg1$ is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4280752). How does this differ from the expansion at $\alpha=1$ and in the region $\alpha<1$.

I see that the numerical plot ($\nu=2$) of the integration is the following
[image]

Thus something very interesting is happening at the point $\alpha=1$.

**Edit:**
If it is difficult to find an asymptotic expansion at $\alpha=1$, then at least can we prove that $f(\alpha)$ has a maxima at that point?

Comment: Letting
$$F_{\nu}(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\nu J_{\nu}(sx)}{e^x-1}\mathrm dx$$
We can see by the Leibniz rule that
$${F_{\nu}}'(1)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\nu+1}{J_{\nu}}'(x)}{e^x-1}\mathrm dx$$
So show this is $0$ $\forall \nu$ (easier said than done). Trying to use the recurrences for the Bessel function might help.

Comment: Set $x=2\pi t$ and use the [Abel Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel–Plana_formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a$ near 1 the 'multiplication theorem' (see wiki on Bessel functions) can be used:

$$ J_\nu(a \ x) = a^\nu \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \Big( \frac{(1-a^2)x}{2}\Big)^n J_{\nu+n}(x) $$

Keeping the $n=0$ and $n=1$ terms gives
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\nu J_\nu(a \ x)}{e^x-1} dx\sim a^\nu \big(C_0^\nu+C_1^\nu(1-a^2)/2 \big)$$
$$C_0^\nu= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^\nu J_\nu( x)}{e^x-1}dx \ ,\quad 
C_1^\nu= \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\nu+1} J_{\nu+1}( x)}{e^x-1}dx$$
This gives a very good approximation near $a=1.$ For instance, with $a=0.99,$ and
$\nu = 0.4,$ the two-term approximation is 0.0037% different from the actual and for $\nu = 0.8,$ 0.0096% different.  Of course, if you have to calculate numerically two integrals at exactly $a=1,$ there seems to be little practical advantage.  The exception to this is if you are doing some theoretical work and you need the analytic behavior as $a \to 1,$ and you really don't care so much for the exact values of
$C_0^\nu$ and $C_1^\nu,$ but that they exist.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a theoretical work for which only the asymptotic form is important. Can you please confirm whether we can ignore the $C^\nu_1$ term while only keeping the $C^\nu_0$ term?

Comment: @FaberBosch For the cases of $\nu=0.4$ and $\nu=0.8,$ both have an error less than 1%.  It seems the larger $\nu$ is, the worse the approximation.  (I've assumed fixed $\nu$ in the analysis.)  I'd think you'd want the first correction term, because the $a^v$ dependence is weak for $a \to 1.$  It's that $(1-a^2)/2 \sim (1-a)$ that shows successive terms will be small.

Comment: Note that $$
C_n^\nu   = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^{\nu  + n} }}{{e^x  - 1}}J_{\nu  + n} (x)dx = } \frac{{2^{\nu  + n} }}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\Gamma \!\left( {\nu  + n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(k^2  + 1)^{\nu  + n + 1/2} }}} .
$$

Comment: This formula for $C_n^\nu$ shows that the $n$th term in skbmoore's series behaves like $$\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}n^{\nu  - \frac{1}{2}} \left( {\frac{{1 - a^2 }}{2}} \right)^n .
$$ Thus, the series converges inside the Cassini oval $\left| {1 - a^2 } \right|^2  = 4$. The presence of $a^\nu$ may require the removal of the segment $[ - \sqrt 3 ,0]$ from this oval.

Comment: @Gary Nice observations.

Answer (score 1):

Via expanding the series for the Bessel function and then integrating term-wise, one gets: $$\frac{(2a)^v}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^m \frac{\Gamma(m+v+1/2)}{\Gamma(m+1)} \zeta(2m+2v+1) \: a^{2m} $$

where $ \zeta(m)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

This, however, is only convergent for $a < 1 $ though.

Comment: This one was given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4277993

Comment: Note that you can simplify the ratio of gamma functions with a [Pochhammer Symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula):

$$\sum_0^\infty f(x)=\frac12 f(0)+\int_0^\infty f(x)dx+i\int_0^\infty \frac{f(-ix)-f(ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx$$

which works for “weak bounds” as stated in the article. Let $$f(x)=\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa)$$

of which the [Modified Bessel Functions of the First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) [**simplify**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-2+pi+x+i%29%5Ev+besselI%28v%2C-i+2+pi+xa%29-%282+pi+x+i%29%5Ev+besselI%28v%2Ci+2+pi+xa%29%29%2F%28-2i+sin%28pi+v%29%29) as $$f(-ix)-f(ix)=(2\pi)^v x^v \text J_v(2\pi xa)$$.

Therefore:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) =\frac12 \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi 0)^v\text I_v(2\pi  0a) +\int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) dx+i\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(-2\pi ix)^v\text I_v(-2\pi i xa) -\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi ix)^v\text I_v(2\pi  ixa)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx\implies i\int_0^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^v x^v \text J_v(2\pi xa)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx+ \int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) dx = \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa)  $$
Rearranging:

$$ i\int_0^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^v x^v \text J_v(2\pi xa)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx+ \int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) dx = \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) \implies i\int_0^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^v x^v \text J_v(2\pi xa)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx = \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) -\int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) dx $$

Factoring and substituting $2\pi x=t\implies \frac{dt}{2\pi}= dx,t_1=2\pi 0=0,t_2=2\pi\infty=\infty$:

$$i\int_0^\infty \frac{(2\pi)^v x^v \text J_v(2\pi xa)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx = \sum_{x=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) -\int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)(2\pi x)^v\text I_v(2\pi  xa) dx\mathop\implies ^{2\pi x=t}\frac i{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^v \text J_v(ta)}{e^t-1 }dt = \sum_{\frac t{2\pi}=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)t^v\text I_v(ta) -\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)t^v\text I_v(ta) dt $$

Factoring and some algebra:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t^v \text J_v(ta)}{e^t-1 }dt =- 2\pi i\sum_{\frac t{2\pi}=0}^\infty\frac i2\csc(\pi v)t^v\text I_v(ta) - -2\pi i\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac i2\csc(\pi v)t^v\text I_v(ta) dt=  2\pi i \frac i2\csc(\pi v)\sum_{\frac t{2\pi}=0}^\infty t^v\text I_v(ta) - -2\pi i\frac1{2\pi} \frac i2\csc(\pi v)\int_0^\infty t^v\text I_v(ta) dt =-\csc(\pi v)\left[\pi\sum_{\frac t{2\pi}=0}^\infty t^v\text I_v(ta)+\frac12 \int_0^\infty t^v\text I_v(ta) dt\right]$$

So our final result according to the Abel-Plana formula is:
$$f(a)= \sum_0^\infty f(x)=\frac12 f(0)+\int_0^\infty f(x)dx+i\int_0^\infty \frac{f(-ix)-f(ix)}{e^{2\pi x}-1 }dx=-\csc(\pi v)\left[\pi\sum_{\frac x{2\pi}=0}^\infty x^v\text I_v(xa)+\frac12 \int_0^\infty x^v\text I_v(xa) dx\right]= -\csc(\pi v)\left[2^v\pi^{v+1}\sum_{ x=0}^\infty x^v\text I_v(2\pi ax)+\frac12 \int_0^\infty x^v\text I_v(xa) dx\right] $$

Note that $$\int x^v\text I_v(ax)dx=a^v \frac{x^{2v+1}}{2^{v+1}}\Gamma\left(v+\frac12\right)\,_1\tilde{\text F}_2\left(v+\frac12;v+1,v+\frac32;\frac{a^2 x^2}4\right)+C$$

where appears the [Regularized $\,_2\text F_1$ Hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/).

The result may be a difference of large numbers.I hope this helps. You can also try [this special case geometric series expansion](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The series and integrals will not converge because $I_\nu$ grows exponentially. Note that the usual notation for the order of Bessel functions is nu: $\nu$ and not a v: $v$.

Comment: Any comments on my observation?

Comment: @Gary Would it be possible to use the Abel-Plana formula in another way or do it’s conditions not let it?

Comment: You may not be able to solve this problem using A-P. I observed from your recent posts that you are quite obsessed with A-P, and try to approach all summation problems with it. It is a nice formula indeed but not a universal answer to all your problems. http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2 tells you the conditions for it to hold, please check these whenever you are trying to use A-P. If the conditions are clearly not met, please do not post a result using A-P.

Comment: @Gary I am just interested because it allows me to turn many Integrals into summations which is very useful. I will keep your suggestions in mind. Thanks.

Comment: No problem with that. I am just saying that in many cases, unfortunately, it just does not work.